# Symfony 4 S3Client::factory issue: 'class Aws\S3\S3Client not found'

Tags: php, amazon-s3, symfony4

I am trying getObject() from aws bucket, but when try s3Client, error: 'class Aws\S3\S3Client not found'

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory([
  'credentials' => [
  'key'    => $key,
  'secret' => $secret
  ],
'region' => $region,
'version' => 'latest',
'scheme' => 'http'
             ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the aws skd isn't installed. Try to install by command

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```